# How to include tpl file in folder above smarty

Tags: php, directory, smarty

Hello I have this structure in my website:

```
templates

.orderpages
..domain.tpl

.nextgen_clean
..root.tpl
```

And in the file root.tpl i want to include domain.tpl, only my $template_dir is always the folder your in so how do i go back a folder because  {include file="../etc} doesn't work.

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

from php page define it like below

```
$file_to_show="page_request.tpl";
$smarty->assign("file_to_show", $file_to_show);
```

now in tpl file show the variable

```
{include file=$file_to_show}
```

and also from tpl you directly include like below

```
{include file=page.tpl}
```

Comment: where do i put the php file?